# Is an API and Router two separate things?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I have a Node.js with Express.js app. I have folders like such:

```
src
   /models
   /router
   /store
   /api/v1
  index.js
```

My `router` folder has a file called `index.router.js` which contains my app's routes e.g:

```
import UserAPI from '../api/v1/user.api.js'
expressRouter.post('/register', function async function (req, res)  {

         await UserAPI.registerUser({
         EMail: req.body.EMail,
         Password: req.body.Password,
         Name: req.body.Name
});
```

The above is a *route* to an *API* so it went into my `index.router.js` file. To perform an API action on this endpoint, I created another file for API functionality called `user.api.js` and it would contain something like:

```
async function registerUser({EMail, Password, Name}) {
  // Import method from model file and perform DB action
});
```

As the application has grown I have come to wonder whether I have made it too complex and created an unecessary layer with a separate file of `user.api.js` which could possibly be refactored to be part of `index.router.js`.

What I do not understand is what is the standard practice of file structuring an API for scalability and should the API endpoints be in a separate file/folder of `api/v1`, `api/v2` or should they be part of the `router`?

One thing that could be advantagous of having separate `api` files is resuability. Because it only contains functions and no routing, the functions could be reused across many different router files.

Comment: Hit the nail on the head with `One thing that could be advantagous of having separate api files is resuability. Because it only contains functions and no routing, the functions could be reused across many different router files.` Not just separate HTTP routes though, you can reuse those same functions to create other APIs (email based, CLI based, serial based, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically re-invented the [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design pattern.

It's not overly complicated. It is considered good practice and encouraged.

### C

Traditionally, what you call Routers is usually called the **C**ontroller. The job of the controller is simply to handle routing, handle argument parsing (request body, query parameters, is user logged in etc.) and sometimes handle validation. This is exactly what Express is designed to do. And Express allows controller functionality like authentication and validation to be refactored into middlewares.

> Note: Sometimes you will see tutorials on the internet where people separate controllers and routes. My personal recommendation is **do not do this**. Express routing has been designed to be perfect for writing controllers. About the **ONLY** reason to separate them is if you have two different URLs that do the exact same thing. In my opinion that is better handled by a redirect.

### M

Traditionally what you call API is called the **M**odel. The model is your traditional collection of objects or data structures that you learned to program with. The model is what performs the application logic. Normally classes or modules that implement models are not labeled with anything. For example a user model would not be called `UserAPI` or `UserModel` but simply called `User`. However, what you name things is just a convention. Stick with what makes sense to you.

### V

The final part of MVC is the **V**iew. In Express the view is simply `res.json()` or `res.render()` with its associated HTML template. This part is 99% already written by Express developers - you just need to tell the view functions what to send to the front-end.

### Your architecture is good

There are very good reasons for separating the model (API) from the controller (router). First is that it allows you to solve your problems without polluting your core logic with parameter parsing logic. Your models should not need to worry about weather the user is logged in or how data is passed to it.

Second is that it allows you to use your model (API) logic outside of Express. The most obvious use for this is unit testing. This allows you to unit test your core logic without the web parts of the code. I also usually write utility scripts that I can use to do things like create a new user, dump user data, generate authentication token so I can use it with Postman etc.

For example you can create a script like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
// register-user.js

import UserAPI from '../api/v1/user.api.js'

UserAPI.registerUser({
    EMail: process.argv[2],
    Password: process.argv[4],
    Name: process.argv[3]
})
.then(x => {console.log(x); process.exit()})
.catch(console.error);
```

Which you can then execute on the command line to create new users without needing to run the server:

```
$ ./register-user.js myemail@address.com 'My Name' 123456
```

It looks like your software is already structured according to MVC. Keep it that way. It will make maintaining and modifying the software a little easier.

Comment: In some of my smaller projects I actually use the utility scripts as ad-hoc tests instead of writing proper unit testing code. It's not as good as a repeatable unit test but it lets you "play" with your application logic to verify functionality

Comment: I feel relieved, really like the script idea as well. Thank you for the answer voted up

Answer (score 1):

API and router are two different things and even from different worlds.

Most of the applications are composed of two basic building blocks, UIs and APIs. UIs is supposed to be for humans and APIs for machines. You can have 0-n UIs and 0-n APIs. There is no rule for that.

*For example UI you might have a webpage for common visitiors, application for paying visitors or those who bought your product and application for administrators. Those are three separate UIs. If one is malfunctioning, others are working.*

*The other example are APIs. There can be separate API for each of these UI. Also there can be APIs for third parties or other microservices of your own system. And again, if one API doesn't work, it doesn't impact others.*

Router is the design pattern for URL control. Or a specific implementation of the design pattern if you wish.

While both UIs and APIs **might** require URL control, the same pattern can be used in both parts of the application system. But it doesn't mean it should be in the same folder. Things for building blocks should be in separate folders. Router, unlike the model, is not a common thing you would share among building blocks.

The folder structure you present here, Im sure you have seen it somewhere on the interent. But I do not consider it mature. I would consider something like that more mature:

```
├── model
├── website-ui
│   ├── routers
│   ├── templates
│   └── index.js    // this is router
├── website-api
│   ├── user
│   │   └── index.js    // this might be a router (API dependent
│   ├── item
│   │   └── index.js    // this might be a router
│   └── index.js    // this is router
├── index.js
└── main-router.js    // this is router
```

*Usually you don't even do `main-router` like that, because this responsibility goes often to load balancer outside of Nodejs. But everyone must start somewhere. This implementation is easy to upgrade later.*

Do not confuse multiple APIs with API versions. In the best case scenario, you never want API versions, ever. You would proceed like this:

```
├── website-api
│   ├── user-old
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── user
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── item
│   │   └── index.js    
│   ├── index-v1.js
│   └── index-v2.js
```

or that:

```
├── website-api-v1
│   ├── user
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── item
│   │   └── index.js
│   └── index.js
├── website-api-v2
│   ├── user
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── item
│   │   └── index.js
│   └── index.js
```

You can't tell now. And you shouldn't care. When you do changes in API, you do them backward compatible. If you can't do that anymore, it means you have done some critical mistakes in the past or large business changes comes in. This is not predictable.

> One thing that could be advantagous of having separate api files is resuability.

Yes, but you can't tell now.

Regarding to your other questions. **Stick to the SOLID rinciples**. Each part of the code should have one specific purpose.
When I see your `router` folder, I have no idea what is there. Well I know routers, but routers of what? There can be everything, yet nothing. Thus not easily extensible = bad.
When I look at my structure, I can more easily predict what is in there.

You should design your architecture regarding to the purpose and not the specific implementations. Lets say you have two APIs because you have two purposes. Are they both REST or GraphQL? Can I share code and remove duplicities? Not that important. Sharing code is actually very dangerous if not done properly. Shared code is the worst part to refactor and it often doesn't provide as many advantages.

> ... I have come to wonder whether I have made it too complex...

Depends, is it a 14 days project? Yes you did. Is it for a year or more? You should go even deeper.